# Quasar loading spinner prevents scrollIntoView function to execute

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar

I want the code to scrollIntoView to some element with given ID after puting data in database. I read that it takes the Quasar Loading Spinner to hide 500ms and that's why the scorllIntoView function doesn't execute. What can I do to embrace this strange issue? I tried to make 500ms timeout on executing scrollUp function but it also doesn't work.
I'm using Quasar Stepper and I want it to scroll to the element on transition. I also tried putStoredata.then() construction but it doesn't work as well.

```
<q-stepper
    :id="formID.PAGE_ONE"
    v-model="store.smallStep"
    keep-alive
    active-color="deep-orange"
    done-color="indigo-9"
    inactive-color="grey-6"
    animated
    vertical
    @transition="formService.scrollUp(formID.PAGE_ONE)"
  >
```

Firstly I click submit button on the form.

```
@submit="formService.validationSuccessSmallStep"
```

It executes the function:

```
public validationSuccessSmallStep = async () => {
    const store = useFormStore();
    await store.putFormData(store.formData);
    store.smallStep++;
  }
```

Which increases the smallStep = makes a transition so it invokes the function

```
public scrollUp(id: string) {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    el?.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

But the scrollIntoView doesn't execute or at least doesn't make the result I want it to.
How can I solve this issue?